# how to restore normal font for comments in Visual sudio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I cannot figure out what happened with my visual studio code. Somehow the comments in editor , programming languages comments, got horribly unreadable. They look like hand written gibberish (comic font?).

Unfortunately I have no idea how it got broken, nor I cannot find the toggle in the editor settings to fix it. Is it my system problem or a bug in latest VS Code?

PS. there are numerous posts out there about how to make the comments in the editor unreadable. I don't judge, but I suspect that's a community movement which introduced this bug. I would like to hear a clarification on this at least to know weather I should file a bug or not.

EDIT:

All right, so it turned out the fonts are part of the color scheme ("Solarized Dark", in this case), as pointed by @rioV8

BTW, I might have clarified that I'm talking about font scheme like that one mentioned here [How do I change font of comments in visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148581/how-do-i-change-font-of-comments-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: select a different theme and see if that changes the highlighting of comments, all text in editor has same font

Comment: thanks @rioV8 indeed the fonts are tight with color scheme. I can just use different color scheme to get expected "normal" fonts for everything in the code.