# How do I change only the font size of comments in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I change only the font size of comments in VS Code?

Comment: Check out this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148581/how-do-i-change-font-of-comments-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'Ctrl and +' or 'mousewheelup and +' at one time to zoom in your code and zoom out.
There are also numerous stunning extensions in VS CODE.
You can search there like the is an extension that will make your comments colorful named "Colorful comments". Just search and choose any extension of your choice.

If you want to change only font size, there is an option in the settings of VS code.

Answer (score -1):

Sadly, there's no real simple solution - that I know of - yet.

#### But what comes near is creating your own font, like recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76688708/14824067), and then [changing the style of comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48840203/14824067).

---

Here's how to change the font style of comments in vscode (Jan 2024):

> You can change the font *style* with the `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` setting:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "comment",
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

> 

For more info on  how to actually create your own font, please see the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48838578/14824067)'s answers or other sources across the web, depending on whatever software you want to use etc.